# Filters inside for loop in pyspark is really slow

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am reading data from s3 bucket and run a for loop and do few filers and find max value. Then running on emr cluster But this is taking hours to run.

df has 1.5 m rows and df_new has 50000 rows. The reason why I converted to np array to see whether it improves the performance for the loop.

Since i am new to pyspark i am not sure whether its a efficient way to do this or a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance

```
df = spark.read.format('parquet').load(os.path.join('s3://', bucket_name, bucket_path_exec+date_val, report_name)

df_new = df.filter(f.col("a") == 1) 
df_new = np.array(trade_report_broker.select("a", "b","c", "d","e").collect())

rows = len(df_new)

for i in range(0,rows):
    aaa = df_newr[i][0]
    eee = df_new[i][4]
    time = df_new[i][2]


    sub = df_new.filter(f.col("a") == aaa)
    sub  = sub.filter(f.col("b") < time)

    max_time = sub.groupby().agg(f.max("eee").alias("MaxTime"))
```

Comment: as you did `collect`, you're not actually using Spark, all the processing is being done locally on one machine.

Comment: If you can add input data and expected output it'll be easy to help